# I have created a quiz, ammending code I have found on the web, but I am having a slight issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have ammended this code, to create a quiz that a user answers questions by checking a radio button.

```
var totalScore = 0;
var numAnswer = 0;


//an array with objects that hold the questions
var allQuestions = [{question: ["Q1: Who was the Top Goalscorer in the 1998 World Cup?"],
                    choices: ["Ronaldo", "Davor Sukor", "Zinedine Zindane", "Thierry Henry"],
                    correctAnswer:1},

    {question: ["Q2: Where was the 1998 World Cup Final Held?"],
     choices: ["Parc des Princes", "Stade Velodrome", "Stade de France", "Stade de Gerland"],
    correctAnswer:2},

    {question: ["Q3: What was the score in the 1998 World Cup Final?"],
    choices: ["2-0", "2-1", "3-0", "3-1"],
    correctAnswer:2},

    {question: ["Q4: Who won the 2002 World cup?"],
    choices: ["France", "Holland", "Brazil", "Germany"],
    correctAnswer:2},

    {question: ["Q5: Who was the Top Goalscorer in the 2002 World Cup?"],
    choices: ["Vieri", "Ronaldo", "Klose", "Ballack"],
    correctAnswer:1}];

//create the questions created by the array, first unselecting all radiobuttons
function createQuestions() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        document.getElementById("answer" + i).checked = false;
    }
    var quizQuestion = document.getElementById("questions");
    quizQuestion.innerHTML = allQuestions[this.numAnswer].question[0];
    createOptions();
}

//change the innerHTML of the label by calling it's ID
function createOptions() {
    for (var o = 0; o <= allQuestions[0].choices[o].length; o++) {
        document.getElementById("a" + o).innerHTML = allQuestions[this.numAnswer].choices[o];
    }
}

//create an HTMLcollection using document.forms and check selected radiobutton and
//corresponding value.
function checkAnswers() {
    var methods = document.forms.radioAnswers.elements.choice;


    if (this.numAnswer < 4) {
        for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
            if (methods[i].checked) {
                answer = methods[i].value;

            }
        }
        //check if answer is correct answer.
        if (parseInt(answer) === allQuestions[this.numAnswer].correctAnswer) {
            this.totalScore += 1;

        }
        this.numAnswer += 1;
        createQuestions();
    } else {

        showScore();
    }
}

function showScore() {
    var printTotalscore = document.getElementById("questions");
    printTotalscore.innerHTML = "Your total score is: " + this.totalScore;
    var removeRadio = document.getElementById("questions_form").style.display="none";
    var removeButton = document.getElementById("next").style.display="none";
}




window.onload = createQuestions();
```

I have gone through the code and I understand that it is using a series of for loops to create the questions, create the HTML for the question answers and finally keeping track of the number of questions.

On the last question the score is not updating properly, like it does for the other questions, I think its something to do with the final for loop but I've debugged it as much as I can but I still can't see how to fix it.

this line `if (this.numAnswer < 4)` is where I think the problem lies, as after the final loop it is going straight to the function `showScore()`, I could be wrong, but if I change the loop to `(this.numAnswer <= 4)` the final question needs to be selected again, and then the score is correct.

Can some one help me solve this please?

Here is the codepen to maybe make it easier: http://codepen.io/Addiosamigo/pen/fFHly

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be the if statement as you correctly identified.  The code behaves this way due to the fact that on the last answer you do not check for it's vadility/update scores.

You need to alter the code to ensure the score checking is carried out even on the last question.  As the score checking needs to be carried out always, the simplest solution might be to move the if statement to cover only the logic of showing next question of the result.

```
for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
    if (methods[i].checked) {
        answer = methods[i].value;
    }
}
//check if answer is correct answer.
if (parseInt(answer) === allQuestions[this.numAnswer].correctAnswer) {
    this.totalScore += 1;
}

// Move the if statement to here
if (this.numAnswer < 4) {
    this.numAnswer += 1;
    createQuestions();
} else {

    showScore();
}
```

This can be seen in action at - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezgtD.  The code also removes some magic numbers.

Comment: to add dynamically answers without changing the if statement all the time, you can improve the code by changing the if to `if (this.numAnswer < allQuestions.length) {}`

Comment: @jan holmes, is this statement controlling the last question number? if numAnswer is less than all questions, add score, if not this is the end of questions, move onto showscore function?

Comment: @kami, I tried your codepen but the last question is not working. I should of known that there was a way of telling the program when the last question is!

Comment: @Addioioi Corrected the issue.

Comment: thanks for taking your time to help me, what was the issue by the way?

Comment: @Addioioi The codepen on the last answer did not validate the if statement correctly.  It required a -1 to the index check.